# Twitter RSS feed double-escaping special characters?? And how do I deal with this using the Universal Feed Parser?

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm parsing a set of feeds using the [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/)

It looks like when twitter generates an RSS feed, it double-escapes certain special characters in the `<description />` field. For example let's say I tweet:

> I can't parse this!

Which is actually

```
I can&apos;t parse this!
```

in HTML entities.

The when you look at the bare XML from Twitter's RSS or Atom feed, it is rendered thusly:

```
I can&amp;apos;t parse this!
```

Universal Feed Parser appears to have some serious problems with this. When you parse out one of the entries and look at how it parses this, you end up with:

```
 I can&amp;apost parse this!
```

which renders on the screen as

I can&apost parse this!

Any ideas how I can get this to behave? When I open the feed in Firefox, the entities are handled correctly, so clearly it's possible to parse the string correctly.

I'm pretty sure that the Universal Feed Parser's behavior is incorrect, but I'm having a hard time finding what part of the code needs to be fixed.

I'm also perplexed because right on the website it states: "3000 unit tests."

Surely one of those tests looks at a feed that contains entities?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering right now I have the following gem in my code to deal with this specific issue: `summary = re.sub(r'&amp;(apos)',r'&\1;', summary)`. That's got to be the ugliest way to deal with this situation, but the only one that works.

Comment: I've gone ahead and cross-posted this as an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/issues/detail?id=286

Comment: I heard back from one of the developers who said the problem may lie in one of the underlying libraries for decoding entities which doesn't recognize `&apos;` as an entity.